# Not able to get value of radio select setting dynmically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

Following is my code in which I am not getting selected radio option for each corresponding rows, let me know what I am doing wrong here.

My Plnkr Code - http://plnkr.co/edit/MNLOxKqrlN5ccaUs5gpT?p=preview

Though I am getting names for `classes` object but not getting the selection.

**HTML code -**

```
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <form name="formValidate" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate="" class="form-validate form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" required="" ng-model="classes.name" class="form-control" />
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <table id="datatable1" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <tr class="gradeA" ng-repeat="cls in reqgrps">
                   <td ng-bind="cls.name"></td>
                   <td><input type="radio" name="groupName[{{$index}}]" ng-model="classes.satisfies"> Choice 1</td>
                   <td><input type="radio" name="groupName[{{$index}}]" ng-model="classes.satisfies"> Choice 2</td>
                   <td><input type="radio" name="groupName[{{$index}}]" ng-model="classes.satisfies"> Choice 3</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
          </div>      
       </form>
    </div>

    <div class="result">{{classes}}</div>
  </body>
```

**Script File -**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.reqgrps = [{name: 'Sub1', roll: 121},{name: 'Sub2', roll: 122}, {name: 'Sub3', roll: 123}];
  $scope.classes = {};
  $scope.result = {};

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $scope.result = $scope.classes;
  };

});
```

**------------- EDIT -------------**

Expected Output -

**classes obj -**

```
{
    name: "Test Class",
    satisfies: [
        "Sub1": "Choice 1",
        "Sub2": "Choice 3",
        "Sub3": "Choice 2",
        .................
        ..................
        ..................
        ..................
        "Subn": "Choice 2",
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here.... you have an empty object, and you are, what, trying to store the radio buttons that are selected into that empty object?  I don't really think you can do that in this way.

Comment: No need to initialize empty objects for using them in ng-model, ng-model will implicitly create the scope property if it doesn't exist already

Comment: @Claies How do I capture which radio button is selected for each subsequent row...lets say for Sub 1 I choose "Choice1" for Sub 2 I choose "Choice3" ..and so on..let me know if it make sense

Comment: this is the best description I know of for how radio buttons work in angular: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/25/radio-buttons-with-angularjs.aspx

Comment: @Claies can I have an example ..or link to start with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to differentiate between each row that is generated by ng-repeat.

You can do this by adding [$index] to each ng-model like this:

```
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="classes.satisfies[$index]" value="Choice 1"> Choice 1</td>
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="classes.satisfies[$index]" value="Choice 2"> Choice 2</td>
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="classes.satisfies[$index]" value="Choice 3"> Choice 3</td>
```

As others have mentioned, you can make the result dynamic as needed by using ng-value to set the value that is passed into the model.

The resulting object is something like this:

```
{"name":"Bill","satisfies":{"0":"Choice 2","1":"Choice 1","2":"Choice 3"}}
```

[See plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6EUJR531NiyHgGUEf7G?p=preview)

Comment: Happy to help ... it's always fun and challenging using ng-model with ng-repeat - $index can save a ton of time, and you can use it as {{$index}} also if you're not in a directive.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a different ng-model property for each row. (Not sure why you'd want to specify the same model on 3 identical rows). In theory you don't HAVE to do this, but as I said, I don't see why you would.

Also you should add a value attribute on your radio buttons:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JN4JuQJH2OvRxoawfDbv?p=preview

From the angular docs:

> value  string
>   The value to which the expression should be set when selected.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

I would also recommend removing the initialization of empty objects in your controller (if ng-model doesn't find the property on the scope it will just create it for you), and I've noticed you've used ng-bind, in case you didn't know that's just a shortcut for the double brackets: `{{}}`

EDIT:

In case your value needs to be a dynamic value you can use ng-value and specify a property on the scope which you can then set in your controller

Comment: ..table(tr) is dynamic ...so i need to handle it dynamically

Comment: What does your table being dynamic have to do with adding a value attribute on your radio buttons?

Comment: "Not sure why you'd want to specify the same model on 3 identical rows" if I will attach different model..it will going to select 3 valus not one...I want to capture the choice for each row ..lets say =>> Sub 1 I choose "Choice1" for Sub 2 I choose "Choice3" ..and so on

Comment: If you specify the same ng-model for all of them, all buttons will jump since you will update every button's value, the ng-model binding is a two way binding so updates in the controller will be updated in the view as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `ng-value` for each radio button, so than Angular will be able to pick those values. You have 3 identical rows so I added some dummy values for them to show the right output.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AxUx83xdotniYru6amGU?p=preview

Also, you can find an explicit example of using Angular radio buttons in official docs here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

UPDATE:

Check edited plnkr, hope it helps!

Comment: I want something like this - For "Sub1" I select "Choice1", For "Sub2" I select "Choice2" and For "Sub3" I select "Choice2" ..note these rows are dynamic..I hope it makes sense to you

Comment: @TechSolvr can you post an example of object that you want to receive after checking all radio buttons ?